# some content of function 'send' is missing

Tags: windows, tcp, winsock, send

I used the tcp protocol to deal the request the client, I found a phenomenon which is some of the content is missing while using the function of 'send'. the code is as fellow:

```
    _stprintf(cData,"[%s]",send_back);
    memset(send_back,0,sizeof(cData));
    int send_count;
    if((send_count=send(service_sock,cData,_tcslen(cData),0))!=SOCKET_ERROR){
        fwrite(cData,sizeof(char),_tcslen(cData),hFile);
        fflush(hFile);
        g_log->print_log("%c%c%c%c",cData[0],cData[1],cData[2],cData[send_count-1]);
        g_log->print_log("buffer len is :%d , send %d bytes",_tcslen(cData),send_count);
        fclose(hFile);
        memset(cData,0,sizeof(cData));
        return true;
    }
```

the send function is always successful, and the value of _tcslen(cData) is equal to send_count and the cData[send_count-1] is ']'.
But when I use the wireshark(a capture tool) to capture the packet which is send out by the socket, I found some content is always missing including the Character of ']'. the content is encapsulated by JSON protocol, so the ']' is important.  the total size of every time send out is 8900 bytes. But when I change the request item one time (before is 100) to 50, there is nothing missed, the size of send back is about 4000 bytes. 
I do not know why this happened.

from my log file, I am sure the array named 'cData' contain the total content, But why the the content from the packets captured by the wireshark is not complete?

Comment: There is no later packet containing the remainder of the data?

Comment: the remaining data is missing, no later packet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that you're using TCP, it already looks wrong.

First off, TCP is stream protocol which is not suited for one time packets ( especially small ) but the benefits are far more greater than just use UDP instead.
Keep in mind that in case of TPC you are not in control you can only make sure that your requests are handled correctly, the actual communication is done by the Winsock library.

Always remember that the send functions len parameter is **NOT** a requirement it's a hint on how big is your buffer and how much you can send in one go, it may return less than you want to send, and this may depend on lot of factors how often it happens, lets say you use the loopback device it would probably never ever do this, meaning that send will actually send what you requested. In a real network it may send it on one go in about 90% or with even less probability.

You have to make sure you send as much as you want, i.e. check for the return value and call send again if it didn't send as much as you wanted and *do the same* on the other side with recv, call recv until you get as much data as you wanted. This method only works if you know exactly how much data you want to send over the network.

As for the loss off data, TCP, I would say almost always sends data, assuming that you checked the return value of send. If there is a network problem, like loss of data you would see the TCP retransmit packet.

For your way of sending data this is more suitable, this is to make sure you really send the amount of data you want :

```
xint xsend(SOCKET s,const char* buf,xint len)
{
xint lastSize;
xint result;

    if (len==0 || s==(SOCKET)NULL || buf==(const char*)NULL)
        return SOCKET_ERROR;

    lastSize=0;
    result=0;

    do
    {
        result=send(s,buf+lastSize,len-lastSize,0);

        if (result==0)
            return 0;
        if (result==SOCKET_ERROR)
            return SOCKET_ERROR;
        if (result==len)
            return len;
        if (result>len)
        {
            xlog(1,"xsend : socket sent too much data [ %i of %i ]",result,len);
            return SOCKET_ERROR;
        }
        lastSize+=result;
        if (lastSize>len)
        {
            xlog(1,"xsend : socket sent too much data ( overall ) [ %i of %i ]",result,len);
            return SOCKET_ERROR;
        }
        if (lastSize==len)
            return len;
    }
    while (1);

    xlog(2,"failed to do xsend");
    return SOCKET_ERROR;
}
```

This code is just a copy paste from one of my projects, xlog is simple logging function, you can figure it out.